# Assign the text to center of the circle image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to assign the text "Upload Profile Picture" in the center of the circle image. But it didn't display the text when I run the code. Below is the html code and css code.
[image]

```
      <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 ">
         <div class="circle upload-button d-flex mx-auto mb-4" style="position:unset;">
           
           <img class="profile-pic" src="">
           <div class="centered">Upload Profile Picture</div>
           
         </div>
            <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/ >
         
      </div>

    .profile-pic {
        max-width: 222px;
        max-height: 222px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
    }

    .file-upload {
        display: none;
    }
    .circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 228px;
        height: 228px;
        border: 8px solid #dbdbdb;
        position: absolute;
        top: 72px;
      transition: all .3s;
    }

    .circle:hover {
      background-color: #909090;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        min-width: 212px;
        min-height: 212px
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding any css to the text div

Comment: I'm using bootstrap class for the text. Haven't add any css other than the bootstrap class.

Comment: You are missing a lot of stuff here. You need to position the text with absolute. If you remove the overflow: hidden; from the .circle you'll see the text dangling below the image which isn't there but still occupying the space.

Comment: Yup didn't notice about it because I'm still new to coding. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.profile-pic {
  max-width: 222px;
  max-height: 222px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.file-upload {
  display: none;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 228px;
  height: 228px;
  border: 8px solid #dbdbdb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: #909090;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 212px;
  min-height: 212px
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 ">
    <div class="circle upload-button d-flex mx-auto mb-4">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="">
      <div class="centered">Upload Profile Picture</div>
    </div>
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/ >
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The code is working now .

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention the property for the class `centered`I have added the property for centered class in my code

```css
.profile-pic {
  max-width: 222px;
  max-height: 222px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.file-upload {
  display: none;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
 text-align:center;
  width: 228px;
  height: 228px;
  border: 8px solid #dbdbdb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72px;
  transition: all .3s;
  
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: #909090;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 212px;
  min-height: 212px
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 large-2 ">
    <div class="circle upload-button d-flex mx-auto mb-4">
      <img class="profile-pic" src="">
      <div class="centered">Upload Profile Picture</div>
    </div>
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/ >
  </div>
```